# Label alignment with enumerate and multicols

Tags: math-mode, enumerate, multicol

I'm writting a math syllabus for my student and I have some problems to align the label of an enumerate environnement when I use it in multicols.

Here is the problem :

[image: wrong alignment]

```latex
\documentclass[parskip=half-]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{4}
        \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\alph*)}]
            \item $\dfrac{6^7}{6^5}=$\columnbreak
            \item $\dfrac{19^9}{19^3}=$\columnbreak
            \item $\dfrac{(-8)^7}{(-8)^3}=$\columnbreak
            \item $\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)^{10}}{\left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)^8}=$
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Can you help me ?

Thanks.

---

**SOLUTION**

I have found here https://www.mathematex.fr/viewtopic.php?t=17954 a nice idea with the use of `\vphantom`.

```latex
\documentclass[parskip=half-]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\newcommand*{\etai}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{4}
    \renewcommand{\etai}{$\vphantom{\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)^{10}}{\left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)^8}=}$}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\alph*)}]
        \item $\dfrac{6^7}{6^5}=$\etai\columnbreak
        \item $\dfrac{19^9}{19^3}=$\etai\columnbreak
        \item $\dfrac{(-8)^7}{(-8)^3}=$\etai\columnbreak
        \item $\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)^{10}}{\left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)^8}=$
    \end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

And the result :

[image]

Enjoy.

Comment: multicols does not align baselines, I would use a 4 column `tabular`

Comment: Yes of course but I want to keep the auto label incrementation end the simplicity of a enumerate like list. I have already use tasks package but I need vertical enumeration.