# vertical alignment of each item within multicols environment

Tags: enumerate, alignment, vertical

In the following MWE, why don't the Answers line up horizontally with the questions? Also, is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,multicol}

\begin{document}

    \begin{enumerate}
        
        \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
            \item Question 1
            \setlength{\columnsep}{-12cm}
            \begin{multicols*}{2}
                \begin{enumerate}
                    \item 1a
                    \item 1b
                    \item 1c
                \end{enumerate}
                \columnbreak
                \begin{enumerate}[label=]
                    \item \textbf{Answer:} \underline{\hspace{5em}}
                    \item \textbf{Answer:} \underline{\hspace{5em}}
                    \item \textbf{Answer:} \underline{\hspace{5em}}
                \end{enumerate}
            \end{multicols*}
        \end{minipage}
        
    \end{enumerate}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: second time today this has come up https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655136/label-alignment-with-enumerate-and-multicols?noredirect=1#comment1632696_655136

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your only goal is to get the "Answer" prompts to align with each other horizontally, then I definitely think that using `multicols` is overkill, and making the vertical alignment problem more difficult. You might just set the contents on the left to a constant width using something like a `\parbox`, in which case the "Answer:"s will align:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,multicol}
\newcommand{\answerline}{\textbf{Answer:} \underline{\hspace{5em}}}
\begin{document}

    \begin{enumerate}
    % using \makebox of a fixed width
    \item Question 1
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item \parbox{5cm}{Something} \answerline
            \item \parbox{5cm}{Something else} \answerline
            \item \parbox{5cm}{Yet another thing} \answerline
        \end{enumerate}

    \end{enumerate}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: aligned answer lines]

If the stuff on the right is always the same width, you might even make it simpler to use `\hfill` just to line them up at the right margin:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,multicol}
\newcommand{\answerline}{\textbf{Answer:} \underline{\hspace{5em}}}
\begin{document}

    \begin{enumerate}

    \item Question 1
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Something \hfill \answerline
            \item Something else \hfill \answerline
            \item Yet another thing \hfill \answerline
        \end{enumerate}

    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Simple and interesting, thank you so much. Is there an easy explanation as to why the parbox fixes the issue and why my original code didn't work?

Comment: Each of the `\item`s starts in the same horizontal place, and the use of the parboxes makes the contents coming after them have the same width (since the parbox takes the full width even if it's not full), and so the same total width has been used for each one when you come to the "Answer:" part.

I think yours wasn't working well because how multicol treats stretchable space to balance columns with `\columnbeak`. I think if you change `\columnbreak` to `\colbreak` it'll be much closer to working.